# delete post facebook using facebook-graph-api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

im a newbie, I'm trying to delete a post using the API but nothing happens. Can you tell me where error is?

here is my controller

```
public function deletepost(Request $request){
        $facebook = Account_chanel::where('id_project', Auth::user()->id_project_sementara)
        ->where('source','facebook')
        ->first();

        $pageId = $request->input('pageid');
        // dd($pageId);

        $userToken = $facebook->facebook_user_access_token;

        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $pageId ."&access_token=". $userToken . '&method=delete';
        // dd($url);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

route

```
Route::delete('facebook/delete', [FacebookController::class, 'deletepost']);
```

my form

```
<form action="/facebook/delete" method="POST">
  @method('DELETE')
  @csrf
   <button type="submit" value="{{$post['id']}}" name="pageid" class="btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-end">delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: URL query string starts with a question mark, not an ampersand.